# email notification to more than one user

Tags: php, email

i've tried this code to send an email notifications to all student in TABLE (student) , of course student's email is already stored in the database , so when i tried this code it only send email to one student ( the first one in the table ) ! i've used "Test Mail Server Tool" to check if the mail send or not , and as i said it's only send mail to one student , how can i send it to all students in table (student) ?

```
 include("connect.php");


     $Load=$_SESSION['login_user'];  
         $smail= "Select Email from admin WHERE ID=$Load ";
     $email= mysql_query($smail);  

    $result3 = mysql_query("Select email from student") or die(mysql_error());
    $row3 =mysql_fetch_array($result3);
    $mail =$row3['email'];
    $to = $mail;
        $subject = "SPMS";
        $message = "You have a new Schedule" ;
    $headers = "From: $email";
        $sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
        if($sent) {print "Your Email Notifications send successfully"; } 
        else {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }
```

Comment: is this in a loop?  I see it only pulling 1 record from your table and sending then moving on.  Right now the code looks like it works as designed.

Comment: Have you tried the usual SMTP way?  `$to = "$email1, $email2, $email3"`...

Comment: However, that's not the best.  To whoever answers this (since I don't know how), please try and use the BCC field...

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the resultset like this,

```
$subject = "SPMS";
$message = "You have a new Schedule" ;
while( $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
 $mail =$row3['email'];
 $to = $mail;     
 $headers = "From: $email";
 $sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
 if($sent) { print "Your Email Notifications send successfully"; } 
 else {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; } 
}
```

Here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for your reference.

**Note:** Mysql_* extensions are deprecated. Use Mysqli or PDO if possible.

Comment: That's +1 for not sipping your coffee while typing :)

Comment: That's coz I just finished :D

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual, it should be possible to send to multiple recipients separated by commas on the "to" parameter, so using your code, `$to = implode(', ', $mail)`

You could use the Bcc header to send to multiple recipients and not disclosing all their addresses.

Also, you might want to check [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php) to ease the development of the e-mail tasks in your site.

Comment: As I recall, this depends also on how the mail server is configured. Do note that using this option might impact code portability. Also, keep in mind that every recipient will be able to see the email address of everyone the mail was sent to. That might prove to cause problems with privacy.

Comment: Yup, that's why I added the Bcc suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would loop over multiple email addresses and then foreach email address, send a mail.

```
<?php

    $addresses = array("mail@example.com", "mail2@example.com", "mail3@example.com");

    foreach ( $addresses as $index => $address )
    {
        // send email to $address.
    }

 ?>
```

Off course, this is not your actual code, but the logic should be clear enough.